# Cascading combobox with html table as datasource

Tags: jquery, html, infragistics, ignite-ui, igcombo

I have some code that I am using to filter some user selections however I would like to use an existing html table as the datasource for the igcombo box as opposed to the javascript array. How can I accomplish this ? 
Here is my code:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://igniteui.com/js/modernizr.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/latest/js/infragistics.core.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/latest/js/infragistics.lob.js"></script>
  <link href="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/latest/css/themes/infragistics/infragistics.theme.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
  <link href="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/latest/css/structure/infragistics.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
  <style>
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      var dsCountry, dsCascTowns, dsCountryCascading,
        dsCountryCascading, dsStatesUSCascading, dsDistrictBGCascading;

      dsCountry = [{
        txtCountry: "3Delta Level 3",
        valCountry: "Ta"
      }, {
        txtCountry: "Account Updater",
        valCountry: "Au"
      }, {
        txtCountry: "DCC",
        valCountry: "Dc"
      }];

      dsCascDistrict = [{
        keyCountry: "Ta",
        txtDistrict: "ALL",
        valDistrict: "AL"
      }, {
        keyCountry: "Ta",
        txtDistrict: "3336",
        valDistrict: "3336"
      }, {
        keyCountry: "Ta",
        txtDistrict: "6064",
        valDistrict: "6064"
      }, {
        keyCountry: "Ta",
        txtDistrict: "6980",
        valDistrict: "6980"
      }, {
        keyCountry: "Ta",
        txtDistrict: "6081",
        valDistrict: "6081"
      }, {
        keyCountry: "Au",
        txtDistrict: "ALL",
        valDistrict: "AL"
      }, {
        keyCountry: "Au",
        txtDistrict: "3345",
        valDistrict: "3345"
      }, {
        keyCountry: "Au",
        txtDistrict: "3346",
        valDistrict: "3346"
      }, {
        keyCountry: "Au",
        txtDistrict: "6214",
        valDistrict: "6214"
      }, {
        keyCountry: "Dc",
        txtDistrict: "ALL",
        valDistrict: "AL"
      }, {
        keyCountry: "Dc",
        txtDistrict: "40",
        valDistrict: "40"
      }];

      dsCascTowns = [{
        keyDistrict: "NJ",
        textTown: "Atlantic City",
        valTown: "AtlanticCity"
      }, {
        keyDistrict: "NJ",
        textTown: "Dover",
        valTown: "Dover"
      }, {
        keyDistrict: "CA",
        textTown: "Los Angeles",
        valTown: "LosAngeles"
      }, {
        keyDistrict: "CA",
        textTown: "San Francisco",
        valTown: "San Francisco"
      }, {
        keyDistrict: "CA",
        textTown: "San Diego",
        valTown: "SanDiego"
      }, {
        keyDistrict: "IL",
        textTown: "Chicago",
        valTown: "Chicago"
      }, {
        keyDistrict: "NY",
        textTown: "New York",
        valTown: "NewYork"
      }, {
        keyDistrict: "NY",
        textTown: "Buffalo",
        valTown: "Buffalo"
      }, {
        keyDistrict: "FL",
        textTown: "Miami",
        valTown: " Miami"
      }, {
        keyDistrict: "FL",
        textTown: "Orlando",
        valTown: "Orlando"
      }, {
        keyDistrict: "SA",
        textTown: "Sofia",
        valTown: "Sofia"
      }, {
        keyDistrict: "SA",
        textTown: "Pernik",
        valTown: "Pernik"
      }, {
        keyDistrict: "PV",
        textTown: "Plovdiv",
        valTown: "Plovdiv"
      }, {
        keyDistrict: "PV",
        textTown: "Asenovgrad",
        valTown: "Asenovgrad"
      }, {
        keyDistrict: "V",
        textTown: "Varna",
        valTown: "Varna"
      }, {
        keyDistrict: "V",
        textTown: "Kavarna",
        valTown: "Kavarna"
      }, {
        keyDistrict: "V",
        textTown: "Balchik",
        valTown: "Balchik"
      }, {
        keyDistrict: "Y",
        textTown: "Yambol",
        valTown: "Yambol"
      }, {
        keyDistrict: "Y",
        textTown: "Kermen",
        valTown: "Kermen"
      }, {
        keyDistrict: "Y",
        textTown: "Elhovo",
        valTown: "Elhovo"
      }, {
        keyDistrict: "Y",
        textTown: "Bolyarovo",
        valTown: "Bolqrovo"
      }, ];

      $(function() {

        $("#comboCountry").igCombo({
          textKey: "txtCountry",
          valueKey: "valCountry",
          dataSource: dsCountry,
          selectionChanged: function(evt, ui) {
            var filteredCascDistrict = [];
            if (ui.items && ui.items[0]) {
              var itemData = ui.items[0].data;
              if (itemData.valCountry == "US") {
                $("#state").css("display", "none");
                $("#district").css("display", "block");
              } else {
                $("#state").css("display", "none");
                $("#district").css("display", "block");
              }

              filteredCascDistrict = dsCascDistrict.filter(function(district) {
                return district.keyCountry == itemData.valCountry;
              });
            }

            var $comboDistrict = $("#comboDistrict");
            $comboDistrict.igCombo("deselectAll", {}, true);
            $comboDistrict.igCombo("option", "dataSource", filteredCascDistrict);
            $comboDistrict.igCombo("dataBind");

            var disableChildCombo = filteredCascDistrict.length == 0;
            $comboDistrict.igCombo("option", "disabled", disableChildCombo);
          },
          itemsRendered: function(evt, ui) {
            ui.owner.deselectAll();
          }
        });

        $("#comboDistrict").igCombo({
          valueKey: "valDistrict",
          textKey: "txtDistrict",
          dataSource: [],
          disabled: true,
          filteringCondition: "startsWith",
          multiSelection: {
            enabled: true
          },
          selectionChanged: function(evt, ui) {
            var filteredCascTown = [];

            if (ui.items && ui.items[0]) {
              var itemData = ui.items[0].data;

              var filteredCascTown = dsCascTowns.filter(function(town) {
                return town.keyDistrict == itemData.valDistrict;
              });
            }

            var $comboTown = $("#comboTown");
            $comboTown.igCombo("deselectAll");
            $comboTown.igCombo("option", "dataSource", filteredCascTown);
            $comboTown.igCombo("dataBind");

            var disableChildCombo = filteredCascTown.length == 0;
            $comboTown.igCombo("option", "disabled", disableChildCombo);
          }
        });

        $("#comboTown").igCombo({
          valueKey: "valTown",
          textKey: "textTown",
          disabled: true
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
<table border cellpadding="1">
 <tr>
  <td colspan="2">
   <table cellpadding="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
     <td>PAGE 1</td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td valign="bottom">PRODUCT</td>
  <td align="right" valign="bottom">CHARGETYPE</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Google</td>
  <td align="right">5954</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td align="right">5456</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td align="right">9057</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td align="right">5658</td>
 </tr>
 <td>Apple</td>
  <td align="right">5254</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td align="right">5136</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td align="right">6757</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td align="right">6158</td>
 </tr>
 <td>Samsung</td>
  <td align="right">5884</td>
 </tr>
  <td></td>
  <td align="right">0096</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td align="right">7777</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td align="right">8181</td>
</table>
  <div class="group-container overHidden" id="before">
    <IFRAME class="frame" id=iframe1 name="iframe1" style="display: none" src="about:blank"></IFRAME>
    <form method="post" target="iframe1" action="SubmitToSomeFile" id="frm" accept-charset=UTF-8 name="frm">
      <div class="overHidden">
        <div class="comboGroup">
          <div>Product</div>
          <span id="comboCountry"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="comboGroup2">
          <div id="state">
            <br />
          </div>
          <div id="district">ChargeType</div>
          <span id="comboDistrict"></span>
        </div>
        <!-- <div class="comboGroup">
                <div>Town</div>
                <span id="comboTown"></span>
            </div> -->
      </div>
      <br>
      <br>
      <INPUT type="submit" class="button" name="submit" value="Run" id=button2 onClick="_submit_form();">
    </form>
    <!-- frame goes here -->
  </div>
  <div id="after" style="width:99%;border:gray 1px solid;display:none;background-color:#ccc;Padding:5px;height:100px;">Thank you</div>
  <!-- Some Content After the form. -->
  <script language="JavaScript">
    function _submit_form(){
    /**** To hide and display frame ****/
   /* document.getElementById('before').style.display = 'none'; */
  /*  document.getElementById('after').style.display = 'block'; */
    var text1 = $("#comboCountry").igCombo("text");
    var text2 = $("#comboDistrict").igCombo("text");
 
 /* To handle text for one or multiple chargetypes */
    if (text2.indexOf(',') >= 0) {
    document.getElementById("after").innerHTML = "Your Product is " + text1 + "! Your ChargeTypes are " + text2;
} else {
    document.getElementById("after").innerHTML = "Your Product is " + text1 + "! Your ChargeType is " + text2;
    
}
 return true
}
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited your code and this should work.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://igniteui.com/js/modernizr.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/latest/js/infragistics.core.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/latest/js/infragistics.lob.js"></script>
  <link href="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/latest/css/themes/infragistics/infragistics.theme.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
  <link href="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/latest/css/structure/infragistics.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
  <style>
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      var dsCountry, dsCascTowns, dsCountryCascading,
        dsCountryCascading, dsStatesUSCascading, dsChargetypeBGCascading;
  
 var array_return1 = []; 
  
  function getchargetypeForCombo()
        {


$(".table__product tr").each(function() {
  var td = $('td', this),
      productitems = td.eq(0).text(),
      productId = td.eq(1).text();

  array_return1.push({
    Product: productitems,
    Chargetype: productId
  });

});

 return array_return1;
        }

        getchargetypeForCombo();

      dsCountry = [{
        txtCountry: "3Delta Level 3",
        valCountry: "Ta"
      }, {
        txtCountry: "Account Updater",
        valCountry: "Au"
      }, {
        txtCountry: "DCC",
        valCountry: "Dc"
      }];

      dsCascChargetype = [{
        keyCountry: "Ta",
        txtChargetype: "ALL",
        valChargetype: "AL"
      }, {
        keyCountry: "Ta",
        txtChargetype: "3336",
        valChargetype: "3336"
      }, {
        keyCountry: "Ta",
        txtChargetype: "6064",
        valChargetype: "6064"
      }, {
        keyCountry: "Ta",
        txtChargetype: "6980",
        valChargetype: "6980"
      }, {
        keyCountry: "Ta",
        txtChargetype: "6081",
        valChargetype: "6081"
      }, {
        keyCountry: "Au",
        txtChargetype: "ALL",
        valChargetype: "AL"
      }, {
        keyCountry: "Au",
        txtChargetype: "3345",
        valChargetype: "3345"
      }, {
        keyCountry: "Au",
        txtChargetype: "3346",
        valChargetype: "3346"
      }, {
        keyCountry: "Au",
        txtChargetype: "6214",
        valChargetype: "6214"
      }, {
        keyCountry: "Dc",
        txtChargetype: "ALL",
        valChargetype: "AL"
      }, {
        keyCountry: "Dc",
        txtChargetype: "40",
        valChargetype: "40"
      }];

      dsCascTowns = [{
        keyChargetype: "NJ",
        textTown: "Atlantic City",
        valTown: "AtlanticCity"
      }, {
        keyChargetype: "NJ",
        textTown: "Dover",
        valTown: "Dover"
      }, {
        keyChargetype: "CA",
        textTown: "Los Angeles",
        valTown: "LosAngeles"
      }, {
        keyChargetype: "CA",
        textTown: "San Francisco",
        valTown: "San Francisco"
      }, {
        keyChargetype: "CA",
        textTown: "San Diego",
        valTown: "SanDiego"
      }, {
        keyChargetype: "IL",
        textTown: "Chicago",
        valTown: "Chicago"
      }, {
        keyChargetype: "NY",
        textTown: "New York",
        valTown: "NewYork"
      }, {
        keyChargetype: "NY",
        textTown: "Buffalo",
        valTown: "Buffalo"
      }, {
        keyChargetype: "FL",
        textTown: "Miami",
        valTown: " Miami"
      }, {
        keyChargetype: "FL",
        textTown: "Orlando",
        valTown: "Orlando"
      }, {
        keyChargetype: "SA",
        textTown: "Sofia",
        valTown: "Sofia"
      }, {
        keyChargetype: "SA",
        textTown: "Pernik",
        valTown: "Pernik"
      }, {
        keyChargetype: "PV",
        textTown: "Plovdiv",
        valTown: "Plovdiv"
      }, {
        keyChargetype: "PV",
        textTown: "Asenovgrad",
        valTown: "Asenovgrad"
      }, {
        keyChargetype: "V",
        textTown: "Varna",
        valTown: "Varna"
      }, {
        keyChargetype: "V",
        textTown: "Kavarna",
        valTown: "Kavarna"
      }, {
        keyChargetype: "V",
        textTown: "Balchik",
        valTown: "Balchik"
      }, {
        keyChargetype: "Y",
        textTown: "Yambol",
        valTown: "Yambol"
      }, {
        keyChargetype: "Y",
        textTown: "Kermen",
        valTown: "Kermen"
      }, {
        keyChargetype: "Y",
        textTown: "Elhovo",
        valTown: "Elhovo"
      }, {
        keyChargetype: "Y",
        textTown: "Bolyarovo",
        valTown: "Bolqrovo"
      }, ];

      $(function() {

        $("#comboCountry").igCombo({
          textKey: "Product",
          valueKey: "Product",
          dataSource: getProductForCombo(),
          selectionChanged: function(evt, ui) {
            var filteredCascChargetype = [];
            if (ui.items && ui.items[0]) {
              var itemData = ui.items[0].data;
              /*if (itemData.Pvalue == "US") {
                $("#state").css("display", "none");
                $("#Chargetype").css("display", "block");
              } else {
                $("#state").css("display", "none");
                $("#Chargetype").css("display", "block");
              } */

              filteredCascChargetype = array_return1.filter(function(Chargetype) {
                return Chargetype.Product == itemData.Product;
              });
            }

            var $comboChargetype = $("#comboChargetype");
            $comboChargetype.igCombo("deselectAll", {}, true);
            $comboChargetype.igCombo("option", "dataSource", filteredCascChargetype);
            $comboChargetype.igCombo("dataBind");

            var disableChildCombo = filteredCascChargetype.length == 0;
            $comboChargetype.igCombo("option", "disabled", disableChildCombo);
          },
          itemsRendered: function(evt, ui) {
            ui.owner.deselectAll();
          }
        });

        $("#comboChargetype").igCombo({
          valueKey: "Chargetype",
          textKey: "Chargetype",
          dataSource: [],
    allowCustomValue: true,
          disabled: true,
          filteringCondition: "startsWith",
          multiSelection: {
            enabled: true
          }
    });
         /* selectionChanged: function(evt, ui) {
            var filteredCascTown = [];

            if (ui.items && ui.items[0]) {
              var itemData = ui.items[0].data;

              var filteredCascTown = dsCascTowns.filter(function(town) {
                return town.keyChargetype == itemData.valChargetype;
              });
            }

            var $comboTown = $("#comboTown");
            $comboTown.igCombo("deselectAll");
            $comboTown.igCombo("option", "dataSource", filteredCascTown);
            $comboTown.igCombo("dataBind");

            var disableChildCombo = filteredCascTown.length == 0;
            $comboTown.igCombo("option", "disabled", disableChildCombo);
          }
        });

        $("#comboTown").igCombo({
          valueKey: "valTown",
          textKey: "textTown",
          disabled: true
        });



    /*    $("#comboTable").igCombo({
         valueKey: "value",
         textKey: "value",
         dataSource: getProductForCombo() 
        }); */

  
     /*    $("#comboChargeType").igCombo({
         valueKey: "value",
         textKey: "value",
         dataSource: getProductForCombo()
        }); */
  
  
        function getProductForCombo()
        {
         var array_return = [];

         $(".table__product td:nth-child(1)").each(function(){
          array_return.push({ "Product" : $(this).html(), "valProduct" : $(this).html() });
         });

         return array_return;
        }

        getProductForCombo();
  
 
  
  
      });
    });
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
  </script>
</head>

<body>
<table class="table__product">
  <tr>
    <th>Product</th>
    <th>Chargetype</th>
    <th>Description</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Apple</td>
    <td>3384</td>
    <td>iPhone</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Samsung</td>
    <td>8800</td>
    <td>Galaxy</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>LG</td>
    <td>8684</td>
    <td>V20</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Google</td>
    <td>8179</td>
    <td>Pixel</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Google</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Pixel</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Blackberry</td>
    <td>4554</td>
    <td>Storm</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Motorolla</td>
    <td>6764</td>
    <td>Z force</td>
  </tr>
</table>
  <div class="group-container overHidden" id="before">
    <IFRAME class="frame" id=iframe1 name="iframe1" style="display: none" src="about:blank"></IFRAME>
    <form method="post" target="iframe1" action="SubmitToSomeFile" id="frm" accept-charset=UTF-8 name="frm">
      <div class="overHidden">
      <!-- <div class="comboTable">
          <div>Table</div>
          <span id="comboTable"></span>
        </div> -->
  
  <!-- <div class="comboChargeType">
          <div>ChargeType</div>
          <span id="comboChargeType"></span>
        </div> -->

        <div class="comboGroup">
          <div>Product</div>
          <span id="comboCountry"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="comboGroup2">
          <div id="state">
            <br />
          </div>
          <div id="Chargetype">ChargeType</div>
          <span id="comboChargetype"></span>
        </div>
        <!-- <div class="comboGroup">
                <div>Town</div>
                <span id="comboTown"></span>
            </div> -->
      </div>
      <br>
      <br>
      <INPUT type="submit" class="button" name="submit" value="Run" id=button2 onClick="_submit_form();">
    </form>
    <!-- frame goes here -->
  </div>
  <div id="after" style="width:99%;border:gray 1px solid;display:none;background-color:#ccc;Padding:5px;height:100px;">Thank you</div>
  <!-- Some Content After the form. -->
  <script language="JavaScript">
    function _submit_form(){
    /**** To hide and display frame ****/
   /* document.getElementById('before').style.display = 'none'; */
  /*  document.getElementById('after').style.display = 'block'; */
    var text1 = $("#comboCountry").igCombo("text");
    var text2 = $("#comboChargetype").igCombo("text");
 
 /* To handle text for one or multiple chargetypes */
    if (text2.indexOf(',') >= 0) {
    document.getElementById("after").innerHTML = "Your Product is " + text1 + "! Your ChargeTypes are " + text2;
} else {
    document.getElementById("after").innerHTML = "Your Product is " + text1 + "! Your ChargeType is " + text2;
    
}
 return true
}
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot bind the `igCombo` to an HTML table. The only DOM element the combo supports binding to is an HTML select. However, you can create a new [`$.ig.DataSource`](http://www.igniteui.com/help/api/2016.2/ig.datasource) object, bind that to the HTML table, and then use it as a data source for the combo by giving it the `textKey` and `valueKey` of the data you want it to bind to. This would still not accomplish the cascading scenario, as for that you need the data to be separated into the distinct groups you want for your other combos, depending on the first combo selection.

Answer (score 0):

You can not bind the `igCombo` to a HTML table but you can create an array with the table and the same specification  that `igCombo` needs like the example code i show you below (look comboTable and getProductForCombo)

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://igniteui.com/js/modernizr.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/latest/js/infragistics.core.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/latest/js/infragistics.lob.js"></script>
  <link href="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/latest/css/themes/infragistics/infragistics.theme.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
  <link href="http://cdn-na.infragistics.com/igniteui/latest/css/structure/infragistics.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
  <style>
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      var dsCountry, dsCascTowns, dsCountryCascading,
        dsCountryCascading, dsStatesUSCascading, dsDistrictBGCascading;

      dsCountry = [{
        txtCountry: "3Delta Level 3",
        valCountry: "Ta"
      }, {
        txtCountry: "Account Updater",
        valCountry: "Au"
      }, {
        txtCountry: "DCC",
        valCountry: "Dc"
      }];

      dsCascDistrict = [{
        keyCountry: "Ta",
        txtDistrict: "ALL",
        valDistrict: "AL"
      }, {
        keyCountry: "Ta",
        txtDistrict: "3336",
        valDistrict: "3336"
      }, {
        keyCountry: "Ta",
        txtDistrict: "6064",
        valDistrict: "6064"
      }, {
        keyCountry: "Ta",
        txtDistrict: "6980",
        valDistrict: "6980"
      }, {
        keyCountry: "Ta",
        txtDistrict: "6081",
        valDistrict: "6081"
      }, {
        keyCountry: "Au",
        txtDistrict: "ALL",
        valDistrict: "AL"
      }, {
        keyCountry: "Au",
        txtDistrict: "3345",
        valDistrict: "3345"
      }, {
        keyCountry: "Au",
        txtDistrict: "3346",
        valDistrict: "3346"
      }, {
        keyCountry: "Au",
        txtDistrict: "6214",
        valDistrict: "6214"
      }, {
        keyCountry: "Dc",
        txtDistrict: "ALL",
        valDistrict: "AL"
      }, {
        keyCountry: "Dc",
        txtDistrict: "40",
        valDistrict: "40"
      }];

      dsCascTowns = [{
        keyDistrict: "NJ",
        textTown: "Atlantic City",
        valTown: "AtlanticCity"
      }, {
        keyDistrict: "NJ",
        textTown: "Dover",
        valTown: "Dover"
      }, {
        keyDistrict: "CA",
        textTown: "Los Angeles",
        valTown: "LosAngeles"
      }, {
        keyDistrict: "CA",
        textTown: "San Francisco",
        valTown: "San Francisco"
      }, {
        keyDistrict: "CA",
        textTown: "San Diego",
        valTown: "SanDiego"
      }, {
        keyDistrict: "IL",
        textTown: "Chicago",
        valTown: "Chicago"
      }, {
        keyDistrict: "NY",
        textTown: "New York",
        valTown: "NewYork"
      }, {
        keyDistrict: "NY",
        textTown: "Buffalo",
        valTown: "Buffalo"
      }, {
        keyDistrict: "FL",
        textTown: "Miami",
        valTown: " Miami"
      }, {
        keyDistrict: "FL",
        textTown: "Orlando",
        valTown: "Orlando"
      }, {
        keyDistrict: "SA",
        textTown: "Sofia",
        valTown: "Sofia"
      }, {
        keyDistrict: "SA",
        textTown: "Pernik",
        valTown: "Pernik"
      }, {
        keyDistrict: "PV",
        textTown: "Plovdiv",
        valTown: "Plovdiv"
      }, {
        keyDistrict: "PV",
        textTown: "Asenovgrad",
        valTown: "Asenovgrad"
      }, {
        keyDistrict: "V",
        textTown: "Varna",
        valTown: "Varna"
      }, {
        keyDistrict: "V",
        textTown: "Kavarna",
        valTown: "Kavarna"
      }, {
        keyDistrict: "V",
        textTown: "Balchik",
        valTown: "Balchik"
      }, {
        keyDistrict: "Y",
        textTown: "Yambol",
        valTown: "Yambol"
      }, {
        keyDistrict: "Y",
        textTown: "Kermen",
        valTown: "Kermen"
      }, {
        keyDistrict: "Y",
        textTown: "Elhovo",
        valTown: "Elhovo"
      }, {
        keyDistrict: "Y",
        textTown: "Bolyarovo",
        valTown: "Bolqrovo"
      }, ];

      $(function() {

        $("#comboCountry").igCombo({
          textKey: "txtCountry",
          valueKey: "valCountry",
          dataSource: dsCountry,
          selectionChanged: function(evt, ui) {
            var filteredCascDistrict = [];
            if (ui.items && ui.items[0]) {
              var itemData = ui.items[0].data;
              if (itemData.valCountry == "US") {
                $("#state").css("display", "none");
                $("#district").css("display", "block");
              } else {
                $("#state").css("display", "none");
                $("#district").css("display", "block");
              }

              filteredCascDistrict = dsCascDistrict.filter(function(district) {
                return district.keyCountry == itemData.valCountry;
              });
            }

            var $comboDistrict = $("#comboDistrict");
            $comboDistrict.igCombo("deselectAll", {}, true);
            $comboDistrict.igCombo("option", "dataSource", filteredCascDistrict);
            $comboDistrict.igCombo("dataBind");

            var disableChildCombo = filteredCascDistrict.length == 0;
            $comboDistrict.igCombo("option", "disabled", disableChildCombo);
          },
          itemsRendered: function(evt, ui) {
            ui.owner.deselectAll();
          }
        });

        $("#comboDistrict").igCombo({
          valueKey: "valDistrict",
          textKey: "txtDistrict",
          dataSource: [],
          disabled: true,
          filteringCondition: "startsWith",
          multiSelection: {
            enabled: true
          },
          selectionChanged: function(evt, ui) {
            var filteredCascTown = [];

            if (ui.items && ui.items[0]) {
              var itemData = ui.items[0].data;

              var filteredCascTown = dsCascTowns.filter(function(town) {
                return town.keyDistrict == itemData.valDistrict;
              });
            }

            var $comboTown = $("#comboTown");
            $comboTown.igCombo("deselectAll");
            $comboTown.igCombo("option", "dataSource", filteredCascTown);
            $comboTown.igCombo("dataBind");

            var disableChildCombo = filteredCascTown.length == 0;
            $comboTown.igCombo("option", "disabled", disableChildCombo);
          }
        });

        $("#comboTown").igCombo({
          valueKey: "valTown",
          textKey: "textTown",
          disabled: true
        });



        $("#comboTable").igCombo({
         valueKey: "value",
         textKey: "value",
         dataSource: getProductForCombo()
        });

        function getProductForCombo()
        {
         var array_return = [];

         $(".table__product td:nth-child(1)").each(function(){
          array_return.push({ "value" : $(this).html() });
         });

         return array_return;
        }

        getProductForCombo();
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
<table class="table__product">
  <tr>
    <th>Product</th>
    <th>Chargetype</th>
    <th>Description</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
  <div class="group-container overHidden" id="before">
    <IFRAME class="frame" id=iframe1 name="iframe1" style="display: none" src="about:blank"></IFRAME>
    <form method="post" target="iframe1" action="SubmitToSomeFile" id="frm" accept-charset=UTF-8 name="frm">
      <div class="overHidden">
       <div class="comboTable">
          <div>Table</div>
          <span id="comboTable"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="comboGroup">
          <div>Product</div>
          <span id="comboCountry"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="comboGroup2">
          <div id="state">
            <br />
          </div>
          <div id="district">ChargeType</div>
          <span id="comboDistrict"></span>
        </div>
        <!-- <div class="comboGroup">
                <div>Town</div>
                <span id="comboTown"></span>
            </div> -->
      </div>
      <br>
      <br>
      <INPUT type="submit" class="button" name="submit" value="Run" id=button2 onClick="_submit_form();">
    </form>
    <!-- frame goes here -->
  </div>
  <div id="after" style="width:99%;border:gray 1px solid;display:none;background-color:#ccc;Padding:5px;height:100px;">Thank you</div>
  <!-- Some Content After the form. -->
  <script language="JavaScript">
    function _submit_form(){
    /**** To hide and display frame ****/
   /* document.getElementById('before').style.display = 'none'; */
  /*  document.getElementById('after').style.display = 'block'; */
    var text1 = $("#comboCountry").igCombo("text");
    var text2 = $("#comboDistrict").igCombo("text");
 
 /* To handle text for one or multiple chargetypes */
    if (text2.indexOf(',') >= 0) {
    document.getElementById("after").innerHTML = "Your Product is " + text1 + "! Your ChargeTypes are " + text2;
} else {
    document.getElementById("after").innerHTML = "Your Product is " + text1 + "! Your ChargeType is " + text2;
    
}
 return true
}
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is excellent! however the actual html table i have to use has no "th" tags or "id" is there any way your code can account for this? I updated the code above.

Comment: Can you get this to cascade based on selection

Comment: I think that yes, but you have to do this with the data repeated on the first column  to filter

Comment: Can you edit the code and show me how you would accomplish this please ive been trying but for some reason i cannot get the data from the first column again in the array

Comment: i hope this works for you... i'm sorry for answer today i'm have not much time...please check the link http://pastebin.com/T7HmDTZA